# minimax Alpha beta pruning on 6 * 6 Tic-Tac-Toe

Tags: python, algorithm, minimax

I am trying to build an Alpha-beta pruning algorithm in my class and I'm still struggling.
I want the return of the function to be a list of position of x, position of y and the score. The original code was minimax without Alpha-beta pruning I got from [this github](https://github.com/Cledersonbc/tic-tac-toe-minimax/blob/master/py_version/minimax.py#L138).

Here is the original minimax without Alpha-beta pruning code :

```
def minimax(state, depth, player):
    """
    AI function that choice the best move
    :param state: current state of the board
    :param depth: node index in the tree (0 <= depth <= 9),
    but never nine in this case (see iaturn() function)
    :param player: an human or a computer
    :return: a list with [the best row, best col, best score]
    """
    if player == COMP:
        best = [-1, -1, -infinity]
    else:
        best = [-1, -1, +infinity]

    if depth == 0 or game_over(state):
        score = evaluate(state)
        return [-1, -1, score]

    for cell in empty_cells(state):
        x, y = cell[0], cell[1]
        state[x][y] = player
        score = minimax(state, depth - 1, -player)
        state[x][y] = 0
        score[0], score[1] = x, y

        if player == COMP:
            if score[2] > best[2]:
                best = score  # max value
        else:
            if score[2] < best[2]:
                best = score  # min value

    return best
```

Here is what I modified and manage to come close to what I want :

```
from math import inf as infinity
from random import choice
import platform
    
def minimax(state, depth, alpha, beta, player):
    """ 
    state: current state of the board
    player: integer, 1 is COMp while -1 is HUMAN
    return a list of [x position, y position, score]
    """
    

    if depth == 0 or game_over(state):
        score = evaluate(state)  # evaluate is a function to see the state of the current board; 
                                   computer win : +1, human win : -1, draw : 0
        return [-1, -1, score]
    
    if player==COMP: 
       
        best = [-1, -1, -infinity]
  
        # empty_cells(state) find the current available positions on the board
        for cell in empty_cells(state): 
            x, y = cell[0], cell[1]
            state[x][y] = player  
            val = minimax(state, depth - 1, alpha, beta, -player)              
            best = max(best[2], val[2])
            alpha = max(alpha, val[2])
  
            # Alpha Beta Pruning 
            if beta <= alpha: 
                break 
           
        return best 
       
    else:
        best = [-1, -1, +infinity]
  
        # empty_cells(state) find the current available positions on the board
        for cell in empty_cells(state): 
            x, y = cell[0], cell[1]
            state[x][y] = player
           
            val = minimax(state, depth - 1, alpha, beta, player)
                             
            best = min(best[2], val[2]) 
            beta = min(beta, val[2]) 
  
            # Alpha Beta Pruning 
            if beta <= alpha: 
                break  
        return best
```

I try to add Alpha-beta pruning to the original code, but its pattern is different from many minimax I found from the internet so I try to write the new one with the pattern I am familiar with. Advice to implement Alpha beta pruning to either one of these 2 codes would be much appciate.